# All fields give this field is required error

Tags: django, forms, required

When I submit this form & all fields are correctly  populated, the form.is _valid() returns false & all the fields give : this field is required error, even the CharField!!!

can anybody see what's wrong? 
this is my form:

```
class TemplateConfiguredForm(forms.Form):
    """This form represents the TemplateConfigured Form"""
    template = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id':'TemplateChoice'}))
    logo = forms.ImageField( widget = forms.FileInput(attrs={'id': 'inputLogo'}))
    image = forms.ImageField(widget = forms.FileInput(attrs={'id': 'inputImage'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'inputText', 'rows':5, 'cols':25}))

    def __init__(self, custom_choices=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TemplateConfiguredForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sendMails/api/templates/?format=json')
        json = r.json()

        custom_choices=( ( template['url'], template['name']) for template in json)

        if custom_choices:
            self.fields['template'].choices = custom_choices
```

this my template:

```
<form id="template_form"  method="post" role="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'create_templates' %}" >
 {% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

    {% buttons %}
    <input type="submit"  value="Save Template"/>
  {% endbuttons %}



</form>
```

this is my view:

```
def create_templates(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = TemplateConfiguredForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            template_configured = TemplateConfigured()
            template_configured.owner = request.user
            template_configured.logo = form.cleaned_data["logo"]
            template_configured.image = form.cleaned_data["image"]
            template_configured.message = form.cleaned_data["message"]

            template = form.cleaned_data['template']

            template = dict(form.fields['template'].choices)[template]

            template_configured.template = Template.objects.get(name = template)

            template_configured.save()
            saved = True


        else:
            print form.errors


    else:
        form = TemplateConfiguredForm()


    return render(request, 'sendMails/createTemplates.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you pass in your form, here:

```
form = TemplateConfiguredForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

is captured by the first keyword argument of your signature:

```
def __init__(self, custom_choices=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

Remove the `custom_choices=None`

Answer (score 2):

You've changed the signature of the form so that the first positional argument is `custom_choices`. Don't do that.

You don't seem to actually be passing that value at all from your view, so you should probably remove it completely. But if you do need it, you should get it from the kwargs dict:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    custom_choices = kwargs.pop('custom_choices')
    super(TemplateConfiguredForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```